# Augmented reality in wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, augmented-reality

I m using SLARTOOLKIT to implement augmented reality in windows phone 7 but the source code provided in the website has some missing dlls. When i run the project I got an error message that SlarToolkitWinPhone.dll assembly reference not exists and i can't find this dll file any where on the internet. Can any one help me please ?

Comment: Hey is it available for iPhone ?

Comment: Link to the source code would help a lot.

At least this tutorial worked well:
http://bit.ly/yv2RKW

Comment: this is not for windows phone 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download SLARToolkit and open the "Slartoolkitwinphonesample.sln" (found in /trunk/slartoolkit.solution directory) and rebuild, this will create "SLARToolKitWinPhone.dll". If you have problems building the sample it is most probably because windows is blocking access to the dlls in the 3rdparty directory. just right clck on a dll to unblock them.